# PHP Laravel order parent by child

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to sort two episodes by their number. This is my code:

```
$neededEpisodes = SharedMethods::getAround($numbers);

$nearEpisodes = TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID)->whereHas('TheNumbers', function($q) use($neededEpisodes) {
    $q->whereIn('episodeNumber', $neededEpisodes);
});
echo $nearEpisodes->get()->toJson();
```

This will output the following result:

```
"nearEpisodes": [{
        "id": 16445,
        "the_numbers": [{
            "episodeID": 16445,
            "episodeNumber": 208
        }]
        }, {
        "id": 16487,
        "the_numbers": [{
            "episodeID": 16487,
            "episodeNumber": 210
        },{
            "episodeID": 16487,
            "episodeNumber": 211
        }]
    }]
```

The problem is that The_Numbers order should be opposite and starting from 210, 211 and then 208.

So my expected output should be id: 16487 and then 16445.

How should I build the eloquent query to achieve that?

## My new output:

```
nearEpisodes": {
        "1": {
            "id": 16503,
            "episodeTitle": "Episodul 183",
            "the_numbers": [{
                "episodeID": 16503,
                "episodeNumber": 183
            }]
        },
        "0": {
            "id": 16190,
            "episodeTitle": "Episodul 181",
            "the_numbers": [{
                "episodeID": 16190,
                "episodeNumber": 181
            }]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sortByDesc`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortbydesc) method of collection as:

```
$nearEpisodes = TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID)
                ->whereHas('TheNumbers', function($q) use($neededEpisodes) {
                    $q->whereIn('episodeNumber', $neededEpisodes);
                })
                ->with(['TheNumbers' => function($q) use($neededEpisodes) {
                    $q->whereIn('episodeNumber', $neededEpisodes);
                }])
                ->get();

$nearEpisodes = $nearEpisodes->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
  return $item->the_numbers->max('episodeNumber');
})->values();

echo $nearEpisodes->toJson();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: If I use get() there is no errors, but the results are still in ascending order :(

Comment: Then try with `sortBy`. Replace `sortByDesc` with `sortBy`. And try again.

Comment: Same thing, nothing changes.

Comment: I have added a `with` in your query, check if it helps.

Comment: After performing this, it went in the right order but it defined a number to each, for the first one [1] and for second [0], which makes second still first ;(

Comment: Check the updated answer, I have added the `values` method.